# How to handle parameters with polymorphism in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use polymorphism and have a `Movil` class as my parent class, and while specific class is `Car`:

```
class Movil:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

class Car(Movil):
    def __init__(self, code):
        super().__init__()
        self.code = code
```

Since every `Movil` takes a name and every `Movil` takes a `code` and is a car, I expect to be able to pass both:

```
class Main(object):
    def main(self):
        a=Car('toyota','001')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().main()
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main", line 1, in <module>
  File "main", line 3, in main
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR: Method parameters are not "inherited" when a child class overrides a parent method. The child class method must explicitly take and forward the parameter:

```py
class Car(Movil):
    def __init__(self, name, code):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.code = code
```

---

Inheritance only integrates *attributes and methods* of the base class into the child class. Notably, if the child class redefines an attribute or method, this *hides* ("shadows") the parent attribute/method *completely*.

For example, if `Car` would not define its own `__init__` then `Movil.__init__` would be used. Related and derived features – such as "the parameters of `__init__`" – are not themselves inherited: they only show up because they belong to the inherited attribute/method.
Since `Car` does define its own `__init__`, this shadows `Movil.__init__` *including its related features, such as the parameters*.

In order for `Car` to take the original `name` parameter, it must be explicitly re-defined on `Car.__init__`:

```py
class Car(Movil):
    #                  v take `name` parameter of Movil.__init__
    def __init__(self, name, code):
        #                v pass on `name` parameter to Movil.__init__
        super().__init__(name)
        self.code = code
```

As an alternative, variadic positional (`*args`) or keyword (`**kwargs`) parameters may be used to forward all unknown arguments:

```py
class Car(Movil):
    #                        v collect unknown arguments
    def __init__(self, code, *args, **kwargs):
        #                v pass on unknown arguments to Movil.__init__
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.code = code

a = Car("001", "toyota")
b = Car(name="toyota", code="001")
```

Be mindful that variadic parameters make it difficult or impossible to replicate some patterns using positional-or-keyword parameters. For example, in the above example it is not possible to accept `code` as both a keyword or trailing positional argument, as is possible with the explicit definition.